AppleScript to Export PPTX as MP4
I'm a novice at using AppleScript. But trying to automate the steps to Export a PowerPoint (Office 365 on macOS) presentation as an MP4 file.
It doesn't appear that the export action itself is scriptable - nor can I get the Script Editor to record clicking thru the UI for File > Export...
So I'm trying the 3rd best thing: using AppleScript to drive the mouse to:

open the File menu
select Export...
select the File Format (as MP4).  <-- Stuck here
set the output file name
click the Export button

But I'm having trouble referencing some of the UI elements - most notably the File Format selector. Is it a "pop up button" or a "radio group"? I dunno. And I don't want to install Xcode (which can suss out these interface elements' names) just to find out for this one task.
My current code:
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        
        -- Bring to fg
        set frontmost to true
    
        -- Click the "File" menu
        click menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        delay 1
    
        -- Click the "Export…" menu item
        click menu item "Export..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
    
        -- Select the "MP4" file format                <-- Stuck here
        click radio group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
        click button "MP4" of radio group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
    
        -- Enter the file path
        keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down} -- Go to folder
        delay 1
        keystroke mp4FilePath
        keystroke return

        --commence Export
        click button "Export" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell

With error:

error "System Events got an error: Can’t get radio group 1 of sheet 1
of window 1 of process "Microsoft PowerPoint". Invalid index."
number -1719 from radio group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process
"Microsoft PowerPoint"

My ask here is for the UI element names in the Export dialog sheet so I can select an output type of MP4.
Or any better alternative approach you can recommend.


I don't think you want to click a 'radio button'. Radio buttons are what you see below the highlighted drop down, eg 'Best for printing'. What you have highlighted is probably a 'pop up menu'.

I have an older version of powerpoint so I see a different layout but there is probably a 'group' ui element in the chain of elements as well. Here is something to try… Duplicate your script but delete everything from the 'stuck here' line down to the 'end tell' lines. Then get the screen coordinates of the dropdown — a simple way is to type cmd-shift-4 and then move the cursor over the dropdown and make note of the coordinates. Add a line click at {530, 200} but substitute your coordinates and then run the script.

It should mimic the clicking and the script should return the full element, eg pop up button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "whatever.pptx" of application process "Microsoft PowerPoint" of application "System Events". Delete the last nine words (because they are implicit given your earlier tell statements). Prepend the line with perform action "AXPress" of  and run the script and see what happens.

By the way, why do you believe that you can't create a movie file without resorting to ui scripting? Have you tried something like: save presentation 1 in ((path to desktop as text) & "bleep.mov") as save as movie?

Hey @Mockman! Ummm, on the Mac, I don't think I can create a movie with Save. The type "movie" isn't a destination from the Save As... dialog - but it's there next to "MP4" in the Export... dialog.
If it helps, I'm using PowerPoint for macOS as part of Office 365, specifically Version 16.89 (24090815).
Re: clicking at specific x,y coordinates, I can try that soon. Sorry I'm not fully following, but where does the "full element" get returned to? I definitely want to try it as that seems like a good way to suss out element names.

It appears in the 'result' section of the script editor window (at the bottom). 'Movie' is just what I see in my version (which only offered 'mov'). I can't tell you what you'll see in your version. Adapt it to whatever options you see in that dropdown. You can try opening the powerpoint dictionary in script editor (File > Open Dictionary…) and seeing what the options for save/save as are (or export). If you paste that particular command into your question, then maybe I can try and be more specific.
